# Codename one online database Connection

Tags: sqlite, eclipse-plugin, codenameone

I am trying to establish an online connection to a database using `Eclipse` and the `codename one` cross platform environment.

As obvious, having your local database within the default folder provides you an access to the database and the connection code is as follows:

```
db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("MyDB.db");
cur = db.executeQuery("select * from user;");
Row currentRow= cur.getRow();
String dataText = currentRow.getString(0);
txt.setText(dataText);
```

I tried to establish a connection to a database on my localhost using the following code, as a prototype to an online connection:

```
String path = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("http://localhost/MyDB.db");
db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate(path);
cur = db.executeQuery("select * from user;");
Row currentRow= cur.getRow();
String dataText = currentRow.getString(0);
txt.setText(dataText);
```

This was giving an error and the connection was not successful.

How can we connect to an online database using the provided codes?

Answer (score 1):

The database that you connect to is not JDBC. It is always SQLite which is an embedded database "in process".

Doing remote JDBC from a device is impractical. Besides the obvious huge security concern this would not work thru NATs connecting devices. If you want to connect to a server side database you will need to wrap the server in a webservice and access that e.g. you can use our webservice wizard: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-remote-webservices-perform-operations-on-the-server.html